# Configurable Products Show Simple Products Price

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, products

How i can replace Configurable Products price with Simple Products Price without any additional price ?.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to try this free extension.
https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple.

This will change the main price with simple price.

**Hope this will help you!**

Comment: This extension working perfectly in product view page but in category page not working how i can fix it plz.

Comment: It will not work on category page caz in category page you did not select any option! So the price will be **0**

Comment: But in my case i've select option in category page so i want to fix it plz.

Comment: Is this still recommended since the extension hasn't been updated since 2012?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a configures simple why not showing the simple with its correct price?
Sound like a pure display issue

Comment: My products has two different type like (item and box) so the item products has a specific price and the box products has a specific price so in configurable products if select item type i want to show orginal price of the item products.

Comment: In this case you could use the simple product price as price if the configured one an  then use the normal price logic to add some amount to the boxed/bundled variant.